# Is deleting a user profile to restore the reputation bad?

Tags: support, user-profiles

I asked two questions which got heavily down-voted and closed. I lost some of the initial reputation I had.
I could delete the user profile and recreate it. In this way, the reputation would be back to 101.

Is deleting and re-creating a user profile to restore its reputation bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That works, and if you do it once or twice, people probably wouldn't even notice.

If you do it repeatedly, that would be a different matter. Accounts which keep on asking poor questions are warned and eventually [banned from asking further questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/295232). Deleting and recreating accounts to avoid question bans (even if the system didn't warn you yet) is a definite no-go and can lead to suspensions.

If you're certain the questions are problematic and cannot be salvaged, it's better to delete the *questions* instead of your account. (This is possible because nobody posted a positively scoring answer yet.) That will restore (with a few minutes delay) the reputation you lost from the downvotes on them.